# What does where do in the below query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
SELECT
    COUNT(emp.empNo)
FROM
    Employee emp
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT dept.empNo
                FROM department dept
                WHERE emp.empNo = dept.empNo);
```

What does the `where` condition(where emp.empNo = dept.empNo) signify in the above query? I get different results with and without the where condition. I'm new to Oracle. Can any one help me to understand?

Comment: This is called a co-related sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query means that you're looking for only those employees, for which it does not exist a department with the same empNo as the employee's empNo.

I guess this is a query to find those employees which are not managers of any department (if we assume that the department's empNo is the empNo of the department's manager).

Still, it would be better if you provide the schema of the employee and the department tables.

Answer (score 2):

your query displaying count of employees which are not present in emp table but present in dept table.
suppose we have two tables emp and dept :

```
emp         dept
1             1
2             2
3             3
4             4   
5             5
              6
              7
```

from the given table we have emp 1 to 5 in both of the tables but in dept table having 2 employees (6,7)which are not present in emp table and your query is displaying count for those emp i.e 2

Answer (score 0):

The query is basically looking for the number of employees who don't belong to a department.

`NOT EXISTS` means that the query enclosed returns no rows. So, for any employee where no matching rows are found in the Department table they are counted.

Answer (score 0):

Same as saying

```
SELECT
    COUNT(emp.empNo)
FROM
    Employee emp
WHERE
    emp.EmpNo NOT IN ( SELECT
                           empNo
                       FROM 
                           department)
```

Comment: I thought so too.. But both the queries are returning different results. I'm wondering what is the difference the condition 'where emp.empNo = dept.empNo' makes in the above query.

Comment: Nulls can affect results when using not in. Can either empno field be null?